# spBayes for non fixed semivariogram parameters

Tags: r, bayesian, spatial

I am considering a Bayesian Gaussian spatial regression model

```
y(s) = x(s) b + w(s) + e
```

where

```
w|theta ~ N(0,k2 H(phi))
e ~ N(0,tau2)
```

Assuming the range `phi` and the `tau2/sigma2` ratio fixed, a normal prior on the regression coefficients `b` and an inverse gamma on `sigma2` reduces the problem to a conjugate Bayesian linear regression problem. Hence no need for MCMC and I can use the `bayesGeostatExact` function.

My question is: if we assume instead that `phi` and the `tau2/sigma2` ratio are NOT fixed we need to specify priors for the spatial parameters as well. 
Assuming a uniform prior for `phi` and inverse gamma priors for `tau2` and `sigma2` ratio makes the conjugacy still hold?

I don't understand why in this case we need to use a MCMC simulation (through the `spLM` function) and there is no equivalent `bayesGeostatExact` function if the spatial parameters are not fixed.

Thanks

Comment: Conjugacy does not hold when phi, tau2, and sigma2 are unknown.